# Is there any difference in meaning between "how" and "what" when each is used to start a subordinate clause?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, adverbs, relative-pronouns, subordinate-clauses

Is there any difference between *how* and *what* in the following sentence?

1. Anny was just telling Wendy **how** she liked to eat the ice cream at the shop.
2. Anny was just telling Wendy **what** she liked to eat the ice cream at the shop.

Do those mean the same thing? Is one an adjective and the other an adverb?

Comment: #2 is not grammatical and has no meaning. Can you tell us why you are asking the question, and where you saw or heard such language?

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *Anny was just telling Wendy [how she liked to eat the ice-cream at the*
>   *shop]*.
>
> [2] * *Anny was just telling Wendy [what she liked to eat the ice-cream at the*
>   *shop]*.

Yes: there is a difference, and no, neither of them is an adjective or an adverb.

In [1] "how" is best analysed as an informal variant of the subordinator "that". Compare *Anny was just telling Wendy **that** she liked to eat the ice-cream at the shop*.

[2] is ungrammatical because unlike "that" and the informal "how", "what" is not a subordinator so it cannot introduce declarative content clauses.